Extend an orthogonal set of vectors to an orthonormal basis in SVD.
I'm learning about Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) and how to compute each matrix in the decomposition $A=U\Sigma V^T$. I know how to compute $\Sigma$ and $V$ and hence most of $U$, since we know that $\textbf{u}_i=\frac{1}{\sigma_i}A\textbf{v}_i$ for $1\leq i\leq k$, where each $\sigma_i$ is a singular value of $A$ (an eigenvalue of $A^TA$).
If U contains $m$ columns, though, where $m>k$, then we need to extend the set $\{\textbf{u}_1,\dots,\textbf{u}_k\}$ to an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{R}^m$ in order to complete $U$.
I'm really not sure how to do this. I think I need to use Gram-Schmidt but this just converts a linearly independent set $S=\{\textbf{x}_1,\dots,\textbf{x}_n\}$ into an orthogonal basis for $\text{span}(S)$. Since we don't know what the other $(m-k)$ vectors are then surely this doesn't apply?
My lecturer has said to find an orthonormal basis in $W^\bot$ where $W=\text{span}(\textbf{u}_1,\dots,\textbf{u}_k)$ but I don't really know how to go about this and whether I need Gram-Schmidt at all. How do I do this?
